# C++ - Changing the sorting for custom QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've implemented a custom QSortFilterProxyModel for sorting a QStandardItemModel. I have overwritten the lessThan() function, because I need to sort it based on multiple roles and not just a single one. For example I'm sorting entries by a priority value, and those with the same priority are further sorted by their timestamp.

Now, what do I do if I want to sort by some other value, for example by a name value in alphabetical order?

I thought I could achieve this by simply separating different cases in the lessThan function:

```
bool MyProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    if (sorting_by_priority)
    {
        // compare priority roles
    }
    else
    {
        // compare name roles
    }
}
```

And have my switch sort function do something like this:

```
void MyProxyModel::switchSort(bool b)
{
    sort_by_priority = b;
    sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
}
```

But this doesn't do anything (nothing is re-sorted after calling this function), so obviously this is not the right approach. (yes, setDynamicSortFilter is enabled)

I have worked around this by creating two proxy models, one sorted by priority, the other one by name, and I simply switching between the two. But I realize that this is an extremely inelegant solution and there must be something much simpler. But since I'm still very new to Qt and the documentation is kind of overwhelming, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate` to indicate that the current sorting is invalidated, i.e. a new sort action should be performed.

Note that calling `sort` explicitly will also work when `dynamicSortFilter` is false or you specify another column or order as can be seen in the code:

> ```
> void QSortFilterProxyModel::sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order)
> {
>     Q_D(QSortFilterProxyModel);
>     if (d->dynamic_sortfilter && d->proxy_sort_column == column && d->sort_order == order)
>         return;
>     d->sort_order = order;
>     d->proxy_sort_column = column;
>     d->update_source_sort_column();
>     d->sort();
> }
> ```